# Hibernate delete many to many association and insert again the same relationship data

Tags: hibernate

Friends, I have the following situation:

1- insert one User object that has a many-to-many of roles.
2- When I change the User and change any attribute, it removes any relationship with roles (JoinTable) and insert it again O_o!
3 Below the stackTrace:

```
Hibernate: update usu_usuario set usu_versao=?, usu_nome=? where usu_id=? and usu_versao=?
Hibernate: delete from usa_usuario_autorizacao where usu_id=?
Hibernate: insert into usa_usuario_autorizacao (usu_id, aut_autorizacao) values (?, ?)
```

The equals and hashCode are implemented.

I tested the equals manually and informs that the collation is the same. I do not understand what he is seeing it differently and applying the cascade.

Another important information: Esotu usand wants the AngualrJS and Jackson to make the JSON parser. I saw the answer and sending the object and are the same information before starting the update I checked equals in the collection and returned true. Really do not understand.

```
@ManyToMany
    @Cascade({ CascadeType.ALL })
    @JoinTable(
            name = "usa_usuario_autorizacao",
            joinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "usu_id", table = "usu_usuario"), },
            inverseJoinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "aut_autorizacao", table = "aut_autorizacao") })
    private List<Autorizacao> autorizacoes;
```

...

```
@Override
    public int hashCode () {
        final int prime = 31;
        int result = super.hashCode();
        result = prime * result + ((autorizacoes == null) ? 0 : autorizacoes.hashCode());
        result = prime * result + ((autorizacoesAutorizacoes == null) ? 0 : autorizacoesAutorizacoes.hashCode());
        result = prime * result + ((confirmacaoSenha == null) ? 0 : confirmacaoSenha.hashCode());
        result = prime * result + ((email == null) ? 0 : email.hashCode());
        result = prime * result + ((nome == null) ? 0 : nome.hashCode());
        result = prime * result + ((senha == null) ? 0 : senha.hashCode());
        result = prime * result + ((senhaAntiga == null) ? 0 : senhaAntiga.hashCode());
        return result;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals (Object obj) {
        if (this == obj)
            return true;
        if (!super.equals(obj))
            return false;
        if (getClass() != obj.getClass())
            return false;
        Usuario other = (Usuario) obj;
        if (autorizacoes == null) {
            if (other.autorizacoes != null)
                return false;
        } else if (!autorizacoes.equals(other.autorizacoes))
            return false;
        if (autorizacoesAutorizacoes == null) {
            if (other.autorizacoesAutorizacoes != null)
                return false;
        } else if (!autorizacoesAutorizacoes.equals(other.autorizacoesAutorizacoes))
            return false;
        if (confirmacaoSenha == null) {
            if (other.confirmacaoSenha != null)
                return false;
        } else if (!confirmacaoSenha.equals(other.confirmacaoSenha))
            return false;
        if (email == null) {
            if (other.email != null)
                return false;
        } else if (!email.equals(other.email))
            return false;
        if (nome == null) {
            if (other.nome != null)
                return false;
        } else if (!nome.equals(other.nome))
            return false;
        if (senha == null) {
            if (other.senha != null)
                return false;
        } else if (!senha.equals(other.senha))
            return false;
        if (senhaAntiga == null) {
            if (other.senhaAntiga != null)
                return false;
        } else if (!senhaAntiga.equals(other.senhaAntiga))
            return false;
        return true;
    }
```

...

Comment: Can you post the code of both entities? There's a very high chance that the issue is in the equals/hashcode.

Comment: Augusto, i update the post, with codes and one more information.